# can't figure out ou the return preg_replace with 2 array

Tags: php, preg-replace

I can't figure out the return of this function...Thank's a lot!

```
function convert_links($string, $base) {
    $pattern = array(',<(a|link|img|script|form|td)([^>]+)(href|src|action|background)="([^>"\s]+)",ie',
                    ',<(a|link|img|script|form|td)([^>]+)(href|src|action|background)=([^>"\s]+),ie',
                    ',<style(.+)url\("([^>"\s]+)",ie');
    $replace = array('"<\1\2\3=\"" . absolute_link("\4", $base,"1 \1") . "\""',
                    '"<\1\2\3=\"" . absolute_link("\4", $base,"2 \1") . "\""',
                    '"<style\lurl(\"" . absolute_link("\2", $base) . "\""');
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);
```

Comment: What PHP version are you using? `e` modifier I thought was deprecated and removed at some point. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php `This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.5.0, and REMOVED as of PHP 7.0.0.`

Comment: I cant figure out what your actual question is.